# Can't seem to be able to parse a Javascript element.value to HTML <input> field

Tags: javascript, html, input

None of the usual tricks work with this, no idea what's going on... I have 3 'if' conditions returning 3 different values as follow:

```
if (addressObj.types[j] === 'administrative_area_level_1') { 
      if ((document.getElementById('county_from').value = addressObj.short_name) === 'County Carlow') {
        document.getElementById('id_location_value').value = 2;
      }
      if ((document.getElementById('county_from').value = addressObj.short_name) === 'County Cavan') {
        document.getElementById('id_location_value').value = 3;
      }
      if ((document.getElementById('county_from').value = addressObj.short_name) === 'County Clare') {
        document.getElementById('id_location_value').value = 4;
      }
```

It works fine when I parse the info to a 'test' database column I create under test_location

```
<input type="hidden" id="id_location_value" name="test_location"  />
```

but I can't get it to work with the actual column I need to use for this project

```
<input type="hidden" id="location-selected" name="location" value="id_location_value" />
```

but the same will work if I put in a random value such as follow

```
<input type="hidden" id="location-selected" name="location" value="64" />
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe because your second input has `location-selected` as `id` instead of `id-location-value`.

Comment: Yes I tried that too... but why is it working when I use a random value like '64' and not when using my element value id_location_value? that's what's puzzling me...

Answer (score 0):

The issue may bbe with this line.

You are trying to assign a value inside `if` clause

```
 if ((document.getElementById('county_from').value = addressObj.short_name) === 
                                                     ^^^
'County Carlow')
```

Comment: the if conditions are working fine, and are returning their respective values.  I'm actually able to parse those values using a 'test' column in the database but it wont work using the actual location column ... don't know where I'm going wrong here???

Answer (score 0):

based on markup in your question,

the first input has an id "id_location_value"

```
<input type="hidden" id="id_location_value" name="test_location"  />
```

so

```
document.getElementById('id_location_value')
```

returns your input element and you can set the value on it.

By other hand the other 2 inputs

```
<input type="hidden" id="location-selected" name="location" value="id_location_value" />
<input type="hidden" id="location-selected" name="location" value="64" />
```

have a different id. 
In these cases

```
document.getElementById('id_location_value')
```

returns null and the browser should throw you an error like

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
```

you could set your input id to "id_location_value"
or you could change the JS to

```
 document.getElementById('location-selected').value = 2;
```